# Connected App - Always Allow for "Allow" "Deny" pop up

Tags: connected-apps, mobile, mobileconnect

For the Salesforce standard mobile app, we have the connected apps created in Salesforce.
Now whenever we login salesforce connected app , it asks for Allow or Deny permissions.

Is there any ways possible to always allow or if it allowed once, do not show the pop up on any subsequent logins?

I already checked the settings that are there. Played around with the IP restrictions, refresh token validity without any success.

Thanks.!